# I can't connect to my Alpine docker image running an SSH server with RSA keys

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux, openssh

Ok so i'm trying to create a docker container that runs an SSH server and connect to it using a generated RSA key. I can create the container just fine, but when i go to connect to the container i am asked for the password. I want to be able to use the generated key to log in. I am using a Dockerfile to do this. I have looked around for similar issues but the solutions don't work for me. I have been at this for a few days now and i'm at my wits end with it.

Currently my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk update
RUN apk add openssh
RUN apk add openssh-server
RUN apk add openssh-keygen
RUN apk add openrc

RUN ssh-keygen -A

COPY key /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN rc-update add sshd

RUN sed -i 's/#PasswordAuthentication/PasswordAuthentication/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

EXPOSE 22
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

I generate a key pair in the same folder as this Dockerfile using the command `ssh-keygen -f key`. After that i build the image with `sudo docker build -t alpine-ssh .`. I then run this with the command `sudo docker run -d --name alpine-container alpine-ssh`. This starts my container and then i go to connect to it using `ssh root@172.17.0.2`. This prompts a response that looks like this:

```
The authenticity of host '172.17.0.2 (172.17.0.2)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:pAmxYCFiCXOt9jOX9TTJyUlUZvoWyB2ySYR1dbX+JbM.
This host key is known by the following other names/addresses:
    ~/.ssh/known_hosts:1: [hashed name]
    ~/.ssh/known_hosts:2: [hashed name]
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

To this i reply with `yes` and i am then prompted with a password request:

```
Warning: Permanently added '172.17.0.2' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@172.17.0.2's password:
```

If i set up a password i can easily connect to it with the password, but i want to skip the password step and try to connect to the container using my pre-generated key.

I have tried many things. From using `ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key` instead of `ssh-keygen -A` inside the Dockerfile, to changing how i edit the permits, even going into the container to try and change the permits. I have not been able to do it. Does anyone have any insight to this issue?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> COPY key /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
> ```

You are copying private key to authorized keys. Private key is private. Copy public key.

```
COPY key.pub /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

> ```
> ssh root@172.17.0.2
> ```

You are not using the private key that you generated. Use the private key you generated, so it can be matched with trusted public key stored in authorized_keys.

```
ssh -i key root@172.17.0.2
```

---

> ```
> sudo docker build -t alpine-ssh .
> ```

Consider giving your user docker access, instead of running `sudo` every time.

> ```
> RUN rc-update add sshd
> ```

You are not using openrc, so this is doing nothing.

> ```
> RUN apk add openssh
> RUN apk add openssh-server
> RUN apk add openssh-keygen
> RUN apk add openrc
> ```

Optimize layers by installing at one go and use `apk --no-cache-dir`. Check your dockefile with hadolint.

> ```
> @172.17.0.2
> ```

Guessing IP addresses is a guess, or requires some `docker inspect` parsing. Use `docker run -P` with `docker port` or just use static port redirection `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:10022:22`.

> ```
> RUN ssh-keygen -A
> ```

Well, the keygen should be unique for the machine. If you are running multiple containers, the safer way would be to run `ssh-keygen` each time you start the container. Overall, it's up to the desing.

---

The following dockerifle:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk add --no-cache openssh openssh-server openssh-keygen
COPY key.pub /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
EXPOSE 22
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-xc", "ssh-keygen -A && /usr/sbin/sshd -D"]
```

Results in the following execution:

```
$ ssh-keygen -f key -q -N ""
$ docker build -t test .
#0 building with "default" instance using docker driver
....
#8 naming to docker.io/library/test done
#8 DONE 1.0s
$ docker run -d --rm -p 127.0.0.1:10022:22 --name test test
d89cfbcc25d966846e4e85cde18b1f94c461ce013ac176ccaab7ec58c9d37ae5
$ sleep 1   # wait for sshd
$ ssh -i key -p 10022 -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o batchmode=yes \
        root@127.0.0.1 echo hello world
Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:10022' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
hello world
$ docker stop test
test
```

Comment: I did not realize there was a flag for picking public key logins when using ssh. Ok i will revise my Dockerfile to see what isn't needed. I checked the IP when i executed a shell in the container.

I have tried logging in with the `-i ` flag, using the public key `key.pub` but i still recieve a password prompt.

Comment: Kindly see the edits, I mixed public with private.

Comment: Is the makefile necessary or just a way to make the process faster?

Comment: Is just to showcase this answer.

Comment: I figured that was the case but even without the makefile, when i try running the code you provided i get this: `root@127.0.0.1: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).`. I am unsure if i have seen this error before. Any ideas why its happening?